# Where can I find tutorials for LibreOffice as a tool for book design?

Tags: tutorial, book

I want to design a book using LibreOffice. Is there somewhere on the net good tutorials for this?

Comment: Please do not build a book in LibreOffice unless you have the tools to create a PDF a printer will accept or a properly formatted ebook for electronic distribution.

Comment: "Where can I find tutorials on..." questions are poor questions, in my opinion. Far better to address a specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

See Philip's comment. LibreOffice is just not a tool for book design. It is a tool for book authoring, and lacks almost all the tools necessary to design a book.

On the subject of book design, there are some quite competent articles on [About.com](http://desktoppub.about.com/od/booksmanuals/Books_and_Manuals_Book_Design.htm), and a fairly good two-part video tutorial here: [(Part 1)](http://krentz.blogspot.com/2011/01/excellent-book-design-tutorial.html) [(Part 2)](http://krentz.blogspot.com/2011/02/mat-thornes-book-design-tutorial-part-2.html)

Keep in mind that there are *two* quite separate things you must learn: book design, which is an entire and very mature subject; and the particulars of how to use whatever software you are working with. You don't become a book designer by learning how to use a layout program, and learning how to design a book doesn't necessarily teach you about any particular application (but it *will* tell you why LibreOffice is not a suitable tool for the job).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But consider this: I really need to use LibreOffice, and don't want to switch to another program. In this case, what to do? Where can I find good advice about **using LibreOffice** as a tool for book design?

Comment: Use the links in my answer for information about how to design a book. The LibreOffice support forums and tutorials will give you what you need to know about how to use the program.

Comment: @Orbis you're asking how to saw a two-by-four with a hammer. Yes, you could bang it to two pieces, but the result won't even remotely resemble what you could've done with a proper saw. You indeed can *write* a book with LibreOffice, but you wouldn't properly *design* one with it. If you're really asking how to write (draft, construct, structure, organize, etc. — the whole writing process) a book with LibreOffice, your question might be better suited to [writers.stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @koiyu I really mean **design**, not write. I write in Notepad++, or any simple text editor. So the question remains. I search for those who posed to yourself this question, to explore LibreOffice as an option to design.

Comment: This question does not remain - it's been answered.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus). If you really want to use Libreoffice, you might want to check out [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/prokoudine/libreoffice-conf-2011-desktop-publishing).